# Campaigns Performance Report wont include campaigns with zero impressions

Tags: google-ads-api

I have an application that gets its data from our Google Adwords account.

Particularly, **It gets the list of ad campaigns along with their results** (number of clicks, cost, etc...). The problem is that, in spite of the google API definition specification say that:

> "The Campaigns Performance report includes all statistics aggregated
>   by default at the campaign level, **one row per campaign**".

I'm only getting the campaigns which have non-zero value in their columns (For example, has been displayed al least one time).

Do you have any idea of **how to include all the campaigns in the report, even when its values are

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: It happened when the campaigns had exactly 0 impressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to get it:

```
  // Report Creation
  $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
  $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
  $reportDefinition->reportName = 'Adgroup performance report';
  $reportDefinition->reportType = 'CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
  $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';

  // Exclude criteria that haven't recieved any impressions over the date range.
  $reportDefinition->includeZeroImpressions = TRUE;
```

The last line specifies that also must be included Campaigns with zero impressions. By default it's value is false, set it to true and you'll get all the info.